# Prove $X$ is a subspace of $l^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

$X \subset l^1(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of sequences which have only finitely many non-zero terms.

How do I prove $X$ is a subspace of $l^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Is the following enough?

Let $\vec{x} = (x_n),\, \vec{y} = (y_n) \in X$

$\therefore \exists\ N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.

$x_k = y_k = 0\ \forall\ k \geq N$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k| \leq C_x < \infty$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|y_k| \leq C_y < \infty$

$C_x$, $C_y \in \mathbb{R}$

$\therefore \forall\ \alpha\, \beta \in \mathbb{R},\,|\alpha|\cdot\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}|x_j| + |\beta|\cdot\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}|y_j| = 0\ \forall\ k \geq N$

And

$|\alpha|\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k| + |\beta|\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|y_k| \leq\ |\alpha|C_x + |\beta|C_y$

Therefore, $X$ is a subspace of $l^1(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Maybe write down explicitly what you have to show as a start. Then try to prove those properties.

Comment: I've added to my question @Keen-ameteur.. is this enough?

Comment: You essentially tried to show that $\ell^1$ is a subspace. You should think what it means for a sequence to have finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: If $x$ has $n$ nonzero terms, and $y$ has $m$ nonzero terms, then what is the largest number of nonzero terms that $\alpha x + \beta y$ can have?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur, I have edited again. I think I am on the right track but I am not sure.

Comment: I think you are over focusing on the $\ell^1$ thing. I assume you know that $\ell^1$ is a vector space. You need to show that $X$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. You should consider @whpowell96 comment more carefully.

Comment: have I not shown that $\alpha\vec{x} + \beta\vec{y} \in X$, therefore X subspace of $l^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: You have shown that $\alpha x + \beta y \in \ell^1$, but not $\alpha x + \beta y \in X$. I think if you wrote this proof with sentences instead of pure logic it would be clearer and half as long.

Comment: Why does $|\alpha|\cdot\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}|x_j| + |\beta|\cdot\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}|y_j| = 0\ \forall\ k \geq N$ not show $\alpha\vec{x} + \beta\vec{y} \in X$?

Comment: I agree, use words then it becomes obvious that X is a subspace.